# PagedList package installed, "missing assembly reference" error in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am following the MVC tutorial, I installed PagedList package, and I cannot use the PagedList reference in the controller.

> The type or namespace name 'PagedList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your references to see if there is a reference to the PagedList assembly.

If there isn't: Try to reinstall the package

If there is a reference: Check if the file actually exists on the location specified.

[Reference example http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-29-92/7750.v20SysRefProps.JPG](http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-29-92/7750.v20SysRefProps.JPG)

Comment: well, It kind of works, but I still get an error in the toPagedList method. Reinsalling only adds PagedList.Mvc reference,  not the PagedList.

Comment: Actually I had to install two of those packages separately, thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 4):

First sorry for my terrible English. In my case, I use the MVC5 in Visual Studio  Community 2015 and I solved the problem this way:

First I delete the cache of Visual Studio and NuGet cache:

- Visual studio - go to %LocalAppData%  \Microsoft\WebsiteCache  and delete all folder.
- Nuget - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935038/6268130%20/%20)

After I use the package manager console to remove PagedList.MVC, then remove PagedList and then re-install them again like so:

- uninstall-package PagedList.mvc
- uninstall-package PagedList
- install-package PagedList
- install-package PagedList.mvc

I holpe that help

Answer (score 3):

Include

```
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
```

in the pgm and run

Answer (score 2):

PagedList and PagedList.Mvc are being installed separately.

**NuGet console install commands:**

```
Install-Package PagedList
Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```

Make sure you've installed both of packages.

Answer (score 0):

I use DNN. My problem was the package (DotNetNuke.Core.8.0.1.239) was outdated.

Check in your solution folder if you have the package installed:

```
..MySolutionFolder\packages\DotNetNuke.Core.8.0.1.239 (your package name)
```

Right click on Solution, go to Manage Nuget Packages.

Click on Browse, search for DotnetNuke.

Install:

DotNetNuke.Core

DotNetNuke.Web

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue was because I was using another more than one web application and they did not use the same framework version :)