# How can I clear the NuGet package cache using the command line?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I can clear my development computer's NuGet package cache using Visual Studio menu *Tools* → *Options* → *NuGet Package Manager* → *General*: <kbd>Clear Package Cache</kbd> button.

I would like to do this on the command line. Unfortunately, I can not find a related command line switch for nuget.exe.

Did I miss something?

Comment: this option is missing in my 2015 VS Version

Comment: yes it is missing. So I am using the accepted answer.

Comment: Microsoft's doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache

Answer (score 923, accepted):

First, download the NuGet command line tool from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Next, open a command prompt and `cd` to the directory to which `nuget.exe` was downloaded.

You can list the local caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

You can clear all caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Reference: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Comment: Works nicely for 3.3 but only for the current user - I had an issue with a corrupt local cache on our build server which was (sadly) running under Local System, so the cache wasn't listed - actual location was `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\`

Comment: Maybe you should run the clear operation under the very same user as the build operation. Either with configuring a dedicated build user, or using a trick to run the clear under Local System.

Comment: Is there any possibilities of removing particular NuGet from cache?              for ex: I want to remove NuGet X from cache and am not aware of NuGet cache location, in this situation how to remove "X" alone from cache

Comment: I had to run `nuget update -self` to update the _nuget.exe_ I downloaded from this link otherwise I got the error `Unknown commmand: 'locals'`

Comment: If you have VS 2017, don't do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665980/1754995 (answer by Ricky below).

Comment: make sure you close your VS since `devenv.exe` might be blocking some package folders and they won't be cleared.

Comment: Be careful with this command. It will cause a lot of downloads and CPU usage in Visual Studio later. Using `dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear` seems more reasonable option. It will provide less disk space though.

Comment: I just cleaned out 34 GBs of data.

Comment: Wow this really jacked up my build quick, thanks alot, whole solution is going nutz with "NU1801 : The local source '/Users/<user>/.nuget/packages' doesn't exist."

Comment: it's --list or -l now or --clear and -c now

Answer (score 393):

In Visual Studio 2022, go to menu *Tools* → *NuGet Package Manager* → *Package Manager Settings*. You may find out a button, <kbd>Clear All NuGet Storage</kbd>:

[image: Button to clear NuGet package cache in Visual Studio 2022]

The steps are similar in previous versions of Visual Studio too.

If you are using .NET Core, you may clear the cache with this command, which should work as of .NET Core tools 1.0:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

Comment: `dotnet nugget locals all -c` does not delete %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\ folder.

Comment: You might probably need to open Visual Studio as an administrator to do this; I usually run VS as a non-admin user, so that was a catch

Answer (score 114):

`dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

If you're using .NET Core.

Comment: I would suggest doing this before you go to lunch.

Comment: The clear was quick, it's just the next build that takes a little while.

Answer (score 97):

The nuget.exe utility doesn't have this feature, but seeing that the NuGet cache is simply a folder on your computer, you can delete the files manually. Just add this to your batch file:

```
del %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\*.nupkg /q
```

Comment: At the time of asking this was the only solution, so was the best answer. Now I've unmarked it, and credited @rmoore's answer after trying it out.

Comment: I needed to clear the cache for a different user (the build identity), and this was the only mechanism that cleared the cache. The command line tool would only clear the caches for my own identity.

Answer (score 42):

For me I had to go in here:

```
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages
```

Answer (score 23):

This adds to [rm8x's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-can-i-clear-the-nuget-package-cache-using-the-command-line/34935038#34935038).

Download and install the NuGet command line tool.

- From Chocolatey → https://chocolatey.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine
- from NuGet.org → https://www.nuget.org/

List all of our locals:

```
$ nuget locals all -list
http-cache: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
packages-cache: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
global-packages: C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\
```

We can now delete these manually or as *rm8x* suggests, use `nuget locals all -clear`.

Comment: what is the point of deleting if nuget will generate all those with every build? why nuget is creating so many folders indeed?

Comment: @batmaci because over time packages get updated and you'll end up with `Batmaci 1.0`, `Batmaci 1.1`, `Batmaci 1.2` where all you need is the latest one

Comment: We had the occasional problem on our build server with not finding NuGet packages in the cache. We solved it by always clearing the cache at the start of the build.

Answer (score 21):

Note that `dnx` has a different cache for feeding HTTP results:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
   CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
   CACHE http://192.168.148.21/api/odata/
```

Which you can clear with

```
dnu clear-http-cache
```

Now we just need to find out what the command will be on the new `dotnet` CLI tool.

...and here it is:

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
```

Comment: I would go with the approach above from Ruslan as I has some issues with packages even passing --no-cache

Comment: Running `dotnet restore --no-cache` worked for me, but I had to do it from a Powershell prompt running as administrator

Comment: this command helped me work out what was going on when `dotnet run` was failing to restore packages but not providing any useful output

Answer (score 9):

If you need to clear the NuGet cache for your build server/agent you can find the cache for NuGet packages here:

`%windir%/ServiceProfiles/[account under build service runs]\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`

Example:

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
```

Comment: I took the liberty of marking the path to make it more readable, and replacing [windows dir] with `%windir%`, which will automatically put you in the right directory when entered into e.g. windows explorer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PowerShell too (same as me).

For example:

```
rm $env:LOCALAPPDATA\NuGet\Cache\*.nupkg
```

Or 'quiet' mode (without error messages):

```
rm $env:LOCALAPPDATA\NuGet\Cache\*.nupkg 2> $null
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up here because I was trying to figure out how to delete a *specific* nuget package from the cache. The answers above talk about deleting all local packages using `nuget locals all -clear`.

In case anyone is interested in clearing a specific package, I'm sharing my findings:

- You can't currently clear a specific package using the `nuget` or `dotnet` cli. There is a github issue open to fix this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5713
- For now, you have to resort to filesystem commands (as some of the answers above mention) to delete the specific package. For mac/linux, it was `rm -rf ~/.nuget/packages/<package-name>`
- What I actually needed was a way to delete the cache of a specific package that I was about to re-publish to a local nuget repository (using a fixed version number to make local development easier). I accomplished this by adding the following to the `.csproj` file of the nuget-packaged library:

```
    <Project>
      <Target Name="DeleteLocalCache" BeforeTargets="Pack">
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(NugetPackageRoot)/$(PackageId.ToLower())/1.0.0-local"/>
      </Target>
    </Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who installed `nuget` on RHEL7 (e.g., from the EPEL repository) using `sudo yum install nuget`, here is where local cache is located:

```
~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I've saw my nugets in this folder (on build server): c:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\