# How can I get Azure push notifications work on UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure

I would like to use azure push notifications, but I can't get it work it writes me when i try to install Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs nuget package:

> Restoring packages for 'App1'. Restoring packages for
>   C:\Users\János\OneDrive\Dokumentumok\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\App1\App1\project.json...   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windowsazure.configurationmanager/index.json
>   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windowsazure.configurationmanager/index.json
>   498ms Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.6 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0
>   is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0. Some packages are not
>   compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0. Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs
>   1.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm). Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm). Some packages are not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm). Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs
>   1.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot). Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot). Some packages are not
>   compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
>   Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.6 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64). Some packages are not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64). Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs
>   1.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot). Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot). Some packages are not
>   compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>   Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.6 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86). Some packages are not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86). Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs
>   1.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot). Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot). Some packages are not
>   compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot). Package restore
>   failed for 'App1'. Package restore failed. Rolling back package
>   changes for 'App1'.
>   ========== Finished ==========

I have followed this tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/hu-hu/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/

But it seems it doesnt work. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

@tixovoxi, it is the nuget issue. I suggest you can clear NuGet package and rebuild your application again. please refer to this post to remove Nuget cache:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935038/4836342