# `dot net restore` fails due to corrupted package

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-restore

I just installed the LTS version of the .NET Core SDK (1.0.0-preview2-003156).  I created a new project by  using

```
dotnet new
```

However, this fails because

```
Failed to create prime the NuGet cache. restore failed with 1.
```

I followed the directions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-to-clear-nuget-package-cache-using-command-line) to clear my local package cache and I am left with this package:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
```

The `4.2.0\ref` sub-directory gives me this error when I try to open it:

```
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

How do I go about clearing this package out or at least getting to the point where the package restore will work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to run chkdsk against my machine.  Because the package directory was on my C:\ drive, I had to reboot for it to run the disk repair.  After the chkdsk completed, I was able to delete the package.