# Linq2db issue witth linqtodb.ttinclude

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, linq2db

Hello I've have a project created with linqtodb with a database in MySQL and make an upgrade so I can work with the Windows 10, the problem grow and I've been forced to remove the linq2db and all dependencies and now when I've reinstalled and try to run the connection with the database the system give me this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     Compiling transformation: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type ~\..\contentFiles\any\any\LinqToDB.Templates\LinqToDB.ttinclude   1012
```

**UPDATE**

I've made a clean of cache give me an error updating the entityframework aparently there's no way to installed because of this:

```
Error       Could not install package 'MySql.Data 8.0.16'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0
```

Any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that those templates work for everyone, I will suspect that somemething lead to corruption of templates in nuget cache from where they referenced. I would first recommend to clear nuget cache (check this link [How to clear NuGet package cache using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277)) and reinstall linq2db packages. If issue still persist - it will be better if you will fill issue with environment/versions details.