# Visual Studio 2017 Package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 NU1202 Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Whenever I try to run my project I keep getting this NU1202 error, for one of the custom packages provided by my company. I've tried deleting the folder and recloning from remote, to no avail.

The odd thing is that it works just fine for other people in my team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer fixed my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935038/1794871

It was due to VS2017 using packages which were cached locally in my machine. They had to be removed and the latest version downloaded.

Comment: Since you're in a .net core proejct which use packageReference format, the installed packages are stored in the cache not in project directory, so you need to clean the cache to solve this issue. You can also use [the option in vs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665980/10910450).