# Installed nuget package is missing files

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using a nuget in my project which is supposed to have a namespace called `ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Time` in the version 0.10.4. For some reason, it tells me the namespace doesn't exist. I'm 100% certain that it does, here's why:

- I published that nuget myself and tested it.
- When downloading the nuget from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChartJs.Blazor.Fork/) and inspecting the nupkg-file by opening it with 7-zip, I can find the dll used for the nuget in the folder `lib`. If I copy that dll outside the nupkg and reference it directly (instead of the nuget), it all works perfectly fine and the code compiles.
- I also looked at the dll (extracted mentioned above) with ILSpy and could confirm that the namespace and its files do in fact exist.

There is absolutely no sign of the absence of these files anywhere.

Since I did some manual testing with the same package version but the package contents were actually different, I suspect caching issues. However, I already tried a few things which helped me previously with a similar issue but none of them worked this time:

- Delete the corresponding folder in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`
- Delete all `bin` and `obj` (and `.vs`) folders.
- Delete all temporary files (using the built-in windows tool)

FYI, there's nothing of interest at `%appdata%/NuGet`.

Does anyone know what the issue could be and how it can be resolved? The current workaround is to directly include the dll but that isn't great.

Ps. The installed NuGet version is `5.1.0.6013` but I'm usually just working with Visual Studio 2019 where nuget is integrated.

EDIT:
The library which is consumed via nuget is targetting `netstandard2.0` (standard library). The consuming project is targetting `netcoreapp3.0` (asp.net core ss-blazor). This alone should not be an issue.

Comment: Is this your library? It might because there is a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web which may need to use a FrameworkReference instead of a Package reference. Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-libraries-via-multi-targeting for multi-targeting

Comment: Yes it's my library. It was a caching issue (as suspected). I have added an answer to clear it up but cannot accept it yet :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a caching issue - it's just sad how much time can go to waste for something this simple. Even though I thought I cleared all cache, I missed a few folders (why does nuget use so many of those?). The solution was to clear *all* the cache using `nuget locals all -clear`, which is also described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935038/10883465).

Clear your cache, kids.