# Syncfusion Charts for Blazor: Cannot read property 'DataManager' of undefined / sf.data is undefined

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

When upgrading [Syncfusion Charts for Blazor](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/chart/getting-started/) from version 18.2.* to 18.3.*, the following error(s) might occur:

> sf.data is undefined
> parseRevive@http://localhost:5000/_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js:1:160271
> initialize@http://localhost:5000/_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js:1:148662
> beginInvokeJSFromDotNet/r<@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31619
> beginInvokeJSFromDotNet@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31587
> E</e.prototype.invokeClientMethod/<@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20052
> E</e.prototype.invokeClientMethod@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20022
> E</e.prototype.processIncomingData@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:18006
> e/this.connection.onreceive@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:11091
> D</e.prototype.connect/</</</i.onmessage@http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:39007

[image]

or

> Cannot read property 'DataManager' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'DataManager' of undefined
> at Object.parseRevive (http://localhost:5000/_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js:1:160312)
> at JSON.parse ()
> at Object.initialize (http://localhost:5000/_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js:1:148662)
> at http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31619
> at new Promise ()
> at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31587)
> at http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20052
> at Array.forEach ()
> at e.invokeClientMethod (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20022)
> at e.processIncomingData (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:18006) throwError
> @ syncfusion-blazor.min.js:1

[image]

How can you solve this / these error(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this error is most likely an error with the nuget package download. This can be solved by deleting the user's nuget cache (Check e.g. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-can-i-clear-the-nuget-package-cache-using-the-command-line)) and doing a `dotnet restore` from the command line on the root level of the project (Where the solution file is).

Answer (score 1):

We have ensured the chart sample with latest **Syncfusion.Blazor 18.3.0.35** and **18.3.0.38** nugget packages, chart is rendering fine and we are unable to reproduce the reported issue from our end. Please find the sample and screenshot below. Can you please clear the nugget cache and ensure the once again.

[image]

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartTest928416015.zip

If you are still facing an issue, kindly revert us.