# Namespaces gone missing - VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Update - seems to be a computer problem? Even when I created a new project, same errors appear immediately. But I did not make any changes to computer.

It is a asp.net core blazor webassembly project. I have been working on it for some days. Today several namespaces went "missing".

What I have tried:

- Uninstall the nuget packages and then reinstall didn't solve it.
- Restart visual studio didn't help
- Reboot computer didn't help
- Cleared nuget cache as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665980/1412765) didn't help.
- Ran a `git restore .` to rollback changes didn't help.
- Delete bin and obj folder then rebuild didn't help.
- `donet restore` command didn't help

The .csproj file content is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
    
    <!--<RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>-->
      <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Pages\Index.razor.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BlazorWasmAntivirusProtection" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BlazorApp.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Build output error text:

```
Rebuild started...
Restored C:\some\path\Shared\BlazorApp.Shared.csproj (in 2 ms).
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlazorApp.Shared, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\some\path\Server\BlazorApp.Server.csproj (in 87 ms).
Restored C:\some\path\Client\BlazorApp.Client.csproj (in 87 ms).
1>C:\some\path\Shared\SharedFunctions.cs(51,17,51,18): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
1>BlazorApp.Shared -> C:\some\path\Shared\bin\Debug\net6.0\BlazorApp.Shared.dll
1>Done building project "BlazorApp.Shared.csproj".
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlazorApp.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(1,1,1,45): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'Router'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(2,5,2,32): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'Found'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(3,9,3,81): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'RouteView'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(4,9,4,65): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'FocusOnNavigate'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(6,5,6,15): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NotFound'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(7,9,7,20): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'PageTitle'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\App.razor(8,9,8,50): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'LayoutView'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\Counter.razor(3,1,3,12): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'PageTitle'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\FetchData.razor(5,1,5,12): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'PageTitle'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\Index.razor(5,1,5,12): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'PageTitle'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(15,1,15,91): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'EditForm'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(16,5,16,31): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'DataAnnotationsValidator'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(17,5,17,24): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'ValidationSummary'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(22,13,22,84): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'InputText'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(23,13,23,58): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'ValidationMessage'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(30,13,30,104): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'InputText'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Pages\LogIn.razor(31,13,31,60): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'ValidationMessage'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Shared\MainLayout.razor(5,9,5,20): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NavMenu'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Shared\NavMenu.razor(13,13,13,72): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NavLink'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Shared\NavMenu.razor(18,13,18,54): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NavLink'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Shared\NavMenu.razor(23,13,23,56): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NavLink'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Shared\NavMenu.razor(28,13,28,52): warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'NavLink'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthenticationService.cs(1,7,1,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Blazored' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthenticationService.cs(2,28,2,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthStateProvider.cs(1,7,1,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Blazored' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthStateProvider.cs(2,28,2,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Program.cs(1,7,1,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Blazored' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Program.cs(2,28,2,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Program.cs(3,28,3,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Program.cs(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\App_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(5,28,5,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(6,28,6,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(7,28,7,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(8,28,8,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(9,28,9,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\_Imports_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(5,28,5,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(6,28,6,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(7,28,7,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(8,28,8,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(9,28,9,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\_Imports_razor.g.cs(110,58,110,68): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\App_razor.g.cs(110,53,110,63): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\_Imports_razor.g.cs(113,70,113,80): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\App_razor.g.cs(113,70,113,80): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthStateProvider.cs(9,38,9,65): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationStateProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Shared_SurveyPrompt_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(5,28,5,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(6,28,6,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(7,28,7,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(8,28,8,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(9,28,9,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Pages_Counter_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(5,28,5,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(6,28,6,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(7,28,7,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(8,28,8,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(9,28,9,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthStateProvider.cs(12,26,12,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILocalStorageService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthenticationService.cs(13,26,13,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationStateProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthenticationService.cs(14,26,14,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILocalStorageService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Shared_MainLayout_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(5,28,5,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(6,28,6,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(7,28,7,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(8,28,8,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(9,28,9,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Authentication\AuthStateProvider.cs(14,26,14,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Pages_FetchData_razor.g.cs(11,32,11,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(3,28,3,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Authorization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\some\path\Client\_Imports.razor(4,28,4,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

Comment: @HenkHolterman it has been added.

Comment: @HenkHolterman deleted .vs folder and rebuilt. Still have errors. Pasted about first half of the errors. The full output was too long and exceeded text limit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added top part of the output. AuthenticationService.cs is indeed the first error.

Comment: IMHO I think there is a bug with VS2022 namespaces. I'm always seeing usings come up for technology we're not using, eg using Azure;

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check _Import.razor:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using BlazorApp1
@using BlazorApp1.Shared
```

I get this error if delete these in _Import.razor, maybe it can help you.

[image]

Comment: Checked _Import.razor and all the using statements are there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have created a new solution, with everything out-of-box, it complains "The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'". So it seems to be something wrong with a wider scope. I uninstalled and reinstalled .net 6 runtime, no use. It seems the only option is to restore the computer.

Comment: @Cal Did you try to repair VS in Visual Stuido Installer?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
dotnet nuget locals all -l
```