dotnet build "Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly" error but only occurs on CI?
I have a simple CI that builds my solution on GitLab. The project consist of a .NET Core project and a WCF project. I am encountering an error after installing the latest version of  Newtonsoft JSON via Nuget; I have version 13.0.3 at the moment of this writing. Below are the errors I am encountering on my CI logs.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\CI_CD\runner\builds\glrt-js9\0\billing-system-projects\billing_project\BillingSVC\BillingSVC.csproj]

What I have tried:

Downloading the branch containing the changes I made that includes the installation of Newtonsoft JSON, and ran it on my Visual Studio to my local machine. The project works and builds just fine.
Re-cloning the entire project to my machine, it works and builds just fine.
Running the same command as my CI dotnet build $PROJ_SLN --configuration <configuration> and it still works fine locally on my machine.
Added nuget restore and dotnet restore before dotnet build command. I'm still getting the same error.

My findings observing the error:

It's only within the CI that it seems not able to restore the Nuget Packages properly after installing Newtonsoft from Nuget.
It doesn't seem to be a setup issue on the CI server. My other projects passes the build step just fine except for this one.
My main branch that contains my production code doesn't seem to have this problem. Newtonsoft JSON is not yet installed on that branch and it passes the build step without issues
The build step passes successfully after uninstalling Newtonsoft JSON package to my WCF project.

Here is my .gitlab.yaml
.ci_server:
  tags:
    - ci
    - hercules
    - cedc-bso
    
variables:
    PROJ_SLN: ./Billing.sln

    # CI server executables
    # NUGET_PATH: ;C:\nuget
    # MSBUILD_PATH: ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin

stages:
  - build
  - va-scan

# Test project integrity by initiating build test on Debug and Release mode.
build-solution-debug:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .ci_server
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - echo "Building solution on Debug mode..."
    - dotnet build $PROJ_SLN --configuration Debug
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - development
    - main

build-solution-release:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .ci_server
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - echo "Building solution on Release mode..."
    - dotnet build $PROJ_SLN --configuration Release
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - development
    - main

# Code vulnerability scanner provided by GitLab
# Please see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/
sast:
  stage: va-scan
include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

Here's the RAW logs containing the error on the CI:
https://pastebin.com/ZcycTkke
Here's my package.json
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

It seems you are mixing .NET (net7.0) and .NET Framework (net472). It looks like BillingSVC.csproj is targeting net7.0. It can't use net472 assemblies. Assemblies that are netstandard2.0 can be used in both net7.0 and net472.

Newtonsoft is currently installed on the solution level. Is it possible to get fixed if I do a separate install on my .NET Core project and my WCF project of that nuget package?

Have you cleaned Nuget's cache? Is your question only in Newtonsoft JSON?

I tried cleaning the Nuget cached from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-can-i-clear-the-nuget-package-cache-using-the-command-line on the CI server.
Still the same error on the CI only. And yes, my question is on NewtonSoft JSON, why is that specific package causing the problem?

It could be a problem with the it itself.
